# Why does cancelling a DetailsView update as part of a wizard clear the form?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to make sure an item in DetailsView2 is equal to 0 before committing any changes in DetailsView1 to the DB. But I just want to report an error and allow the user to continue editing. Currently, clicking "Update" in DetailsView1 clears the page.

Here's the code behind:

```
protected void DetailsView1_Updating(object sender, DetailsViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
    if (DetailsView2.Rows[0].Cells[1].Text != "0")
    {
        DetailsView2.Rows[1].Cells[1].Visible = true;  // Display error message
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Here's the frontend:

```
<asp:DetailsView 
    ID="DetailsView1" 
    runat="server" 
    AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" 
    DefaultMode="Edit" 
    OnItemUpdating="DetailsView1_Updating">
    ...
```

Both these DetailViews are part of a wizard, but I'm not certain that makes any difference.

Comment: Usually, this is caused by problems binding data on postback.  Take a look at how you bind the data. It might be losing it in the form_load event. Add breakpoints to confirm that your data is binding properly each postback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a listener on the ItemCommand event clearing the ID of the object the form was designed to edit. Since that ID gets overwritten anyway when a new object is selected in the wizard, I simply removed that logic. Now data stays in place after validation so that it can be fixed if validation fails.

For what it's worth, I found the errant event handler by setting a break point on every method in the codebehind and just watching the command flow.